# How do you test the results of 'client.execute' in Nighwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Here's the api for `client.execute`. I'm able to get a value back, but how am I able to actually test that the value is correct? I don't see a generic `assert` method anywhere.

http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write generic asserts with `client.assert.equal`. See more in the unit testing section http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-unit-tests

Answer (score 11):

Nightwatch.js extends [Node.js assert module](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html), so you can also use any of the available methods there in your tests.

```
'some suite': function (client) {

  client.execute(
    function(greet){
      return greet + " there!";
    },
    "Hello",
    function(result){
      client.assert.equal(result, "Hello there!");
    }
  );

}
```

Comment: Best answer, it saved my day (was hunting for many hours :-( )

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following code:

```
'some suite': function(client) {
    client.execute(function(args) {
        return args  + ' there!';
    }, ['Hello'], function(result) {
        client.assert.equal(result.value, "Hello there!");
    });
},
```